# Two arrows rotating inside a circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, rotation

So, the basic idea that I need to achieve is to have a simple circle that goes from 0 to 360 degrees.

Inside that circle are two arrows. I need them to rotate inside the circle.

One arrow needs to rotate degree per degree until it reaches a specified angle. The other needs to go directly to that angle.

So your arrows would both start at 0 degrees and if you specified you wanted to go to 100 degrees, one arrow would instantly jump and point towards 100 degrees, while the other would gradualy make it's way to 100 degrees.

EDIT:

Sorry about my lack of skill with stackoverflow (I just realised I never included a question into my question...).  So I managed to get simple arrows down in canvas earlier through another question on stackoverflow, but when I started looking into actualy rotating the arrows, I just got lost in the code.

I guess my question was this:  how can I apply rotation to my two arrows based on a degree value chosen by the user?

So here's what I managed to make my arrows with:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>

<script langauage="javascript">
<!--
ctx = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
canvas_arrow(ctx,50,50,100,50);
canvas_arrow(ctx,50,50,10,30);
ctx.stroke();


function canvas_arrow(context, fromx, fromy, tox, toy){
    var headlen = 10;   // length of head in pixels
    var dx = tox-fromx;
    var dy = toy-fromy;
    var angle = Math.atan2(dy,dx);
    context.moveTo(fromx, fromy);
    context.lineTo(tox, toy);
    context.lineTo(tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle-Math.PI/6),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle-Math.PI/6));
    context.moveTo(tox, toy);
    context.lineTo(tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle+Math.PI/6),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle+Math.PI/6));
}
-->
</script>
</body>
</head>
```

The arrows are fine, but getting one of them to rotate while the other one jumps to the desired degree value is what I find hard. I can't find any examples or ideas on how to make them move based on a degree value given by a user.

Comment: That's interesting, but what's your question?

Comment: That's a nice idea. What about it?

Comment: I think you should edit your question and make it more clarify, or else you will get down vote by some "super cruel" seniors here :)

Comment: @DoanCuong a down-vote is not so bad when you have `1` total points :)

Comment: I just notice that and totally agree :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Next time you ask a question add some code of what you tried. If you can you always try to setup an online jsBin demo too. No-one's probably write you code for free. unless is totally bored :). You risk your question to get closed.

Answer (score 2):

With **jQuery** you can get the **degrees** depending on the mouse position -over your element, and apply the **CSS3 transform rotate** deg and set the animation transition time:

```js
const $el = $('#circle'),
  $cir = $el.children();

$el.on('click', evt => {
  const o = $(evt.target).offset(),
    rad = $el.width() / 2,
    mPos = {
      x: evt.pageX - o.left,
      y: evt.pageY - o.top
    },
    a = Math.atan2(mPos.x - rad, mPos.y - rad),
    d = -a / (Math.PI / 180) + 180;

  $cir.css({transform: `rotate(${d}deg)`});
});
```

```css
#circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  user-select: none; /* prevent text highlight */
  cursor: pointer;
}

#circle>* {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}

#circle1 {
  background: #eee;
  transition: 1.3s;
}

#circle2 {
  background: #fff;
  transition: 0.3s;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: calc(150px - 40px);
  height: calc(150px - 40px);
}
```

```html
<div id="circle">
  <div id="circle1">&#9660;</div>
  <div id="circle2">&#9650;</div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: [See here.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181774/stricter-kbd-usage-rules)

Comment: This works like a charm, I'm playing around with it to try and modify the markers to make them into arrows. 

A problem I am coming up with is adding marks to the grey circle with degrees on it.

I am trying to add marks every 15 degrees, but can't seem to find out how.

I was thinking a mix of html, css and sass are probably best? Similar to this [link](http://css-tricks.com/set-text-on-a-circle/)

Comment: @JulienDesaulniers no please, just create a background image for that element - that has radially displaced 24 lines at 15°. That's all you need.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan : Would it be possible for the background to be fixed and have the arrow move over it, without the background itself moving?

Comment: This is pure genius, great solution!

Comment: @Seano666 :) thx glad you like it! Here I created a cool implementation: http://dribbble.com/shots/1146512-Audio-Controllers-2 (link in the description)

Comment: Your link to the site ain't working. No output is available. Put something that works like fiddle.

Comment: @Chillzy sorry to see you downvoting. Notice that this answer was made in 2013, since than the URLs to jQuery become invalid (the reason the examples stopped working) all you had to do was detect the problem in Dev. console: *`$` is not defined*, and simply use a valid path to the jQuery resource. I'll use the SO snippets instead of jsBin. Also, take in mind that *a kindergarten's Fiddle* are **not a must have** since the provided code **was working perfectly fine**. But thanks for letting me know - will edit soon. Hoping to not get another downer in 2026 ;)